# how to trick Thread.start() to run more than once in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, kivy, p2p

**intro**

***im building a p2pvideo call app.***

**from the side that gets the call**

i have the kivy main loop running as a thread with a another thread slistner_bind_thread.start() (a socket.bind function) that listens to calls and returns a pickup quote or a decline quote, if its picked up quote it starts another thread sstream_bind_thread.start() which cv2capture and pack send the feed (socket.bind).

**from the side that calls**

i have the same kivy main loop running as a thread with another thread scall_CON_thread.start() (socket.connect) that starts with a call button and waits for either a pickup quote or a decline from the other side if its picked up quote it calls for another threads feed_CON_thread.start() that revieves an opencv2 data packets.

**Problem**

when i make the call everything works as expected but when hanging up and calling again i understood that threads cant be started more than once. if i attempt to use anything else the gui gets bugged obviously.
i have some ideas but i dont know if they will work or not, if anyone can suggest something PLEASE at least a comment.

**here is the main.py**

```
import socket 
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
import kivy
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.core.camera import Camera
from kivy.graphics import *
import time
import os
from pathlib import Path 
import cv2                                          
import struct
import threading
import pickle
Builder.load_file('the.kv')

  ##########go to line 233 and 240

################################ GLOBAL VARIABLAS  BEGIN  #######################
                ########    PORTS   ############
sfeed_CON_port = 2430
slistner_bind_port = 1330
sstream_bind_port = 2430
scall_CON_port = 1330

            ###################### ################# #########

action = ''
endcall = False
endcall_string = '' 
myip = ''
sfeed_cv_frame_recieve = None
incall_add = 'nocalls'
outcall_add = ''


################################ GLOBAL VARIABLS END #########################



def feedconnect():
    global outcall_add, sfeed_CON_port, endcall  ########### addr conn from listenr
    global sfeed_cv_frame_recieve
    try:
        sfeed_CON_ad = outcall_add
        sfeed_CON = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sfeed_CON.connect((sfeed_CON_ad, sfeed_CON_port))

        data = b""
        payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
        while endcall == False:
            while len(data) < payload_size:
                packet = sfeed_CON.recv(4*1024)
                if not packet: break
                data+=packet
            packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
            data =data[payload_size:]
            msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]

            while len(data) < msg_size:
                data+=sfeed_CON.recv(4*2024)
            frame_data = data[:msg_size]
            data =data[msg_size:]
            frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

            sfeed_cv_frame_recieve = frame

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF     
            if endcall == True:
                print(endcall_string + '  closing feedconnect() socket')
                sfeed_CON.close()
                break
        sfeed_CON.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("client: " + outcall_add + 'disconnected ')


sfeed_CON_thread = threading.Thread(target = feedconnect)   ####### THREAD

def callconnect():
    global outcall_add, scall_CON_port

    scall_CON_ad = outcall_add
    scall_CON = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    scall_CON.connect((scall_CON_ad, scall_CON_port))

    print('callconnect is waiting for an answer from  :' + scall_CON_ad + ' on port: ' + str(scall_CON_port))   
    time.sleep(15)

    answer = scall_CON.recv(4*1024)
    decoded_answer = answer.decode("utf-8")

    if decoded_answer == 'decilned':
            print(decoded_answer)

    elif decoded_answer == 'picked up' :
            print(decoded_answer)

            f = True       ############  to check
            #feedconnect()
            sfeed_CON_thread.start()
            print(f)
    else:
            print(decoded_answer)

    scall_CON.close()

scall_CON_thread = threading.Thread(target = callconnect) #### THREAD

def streambind():
    global myip, sstream_bind_port

    sstream_bind_ad = myip
    sstream_bind = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sstream_bind.bind((sstream_bind_ad, sstream_bind_port))
    print('myip is : ' + myip + ' from streambind() ' )
    sstream_bind.listen(5)

    sstream_bind_sclient, sstream_bind_sclient_ad = sstream_bind.accept()
    
    if sstream_bind_sclient:
        opcv_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while (opcv_vid.isOpened()):
            try:
                img, frame = opcv_vid.read()
                pickled_frame = pickle.dumps(frame)
                struct_pickled_frame = struct.pack("Q", len(pickled_frame)) + pickled_frame
                sstream_bind_sclient.sendall(struct_pickled_frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if key == ord('q'):
                    slistner_bind_sclient.close()
            except:
                endcall = True
                endcall_string ='endcall'
                print(endcall_string, endcall)
                sstream_bind.close()
                
                break
                #sstream_bind_sclient.close()      ############ hint i am closing only the client

sstream_bind_thread = threading.Thread(target = streambind)    #### THREAD

def listnerbind():
    global myip, slistner_bind_port, incall_add
    global action
    host_name = socket.gethostname()
    myip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name + ".local")
    slistner_bind_ad = myip

    slistner_bind = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    slistner_bind.bind((slistner_bind_ad, slistner_bind_port))
    slistner_bind.listen(10)
    print('listnerbind() on thread')
    print('listning for calls in: ' + slistner_bind_ad + ' on port: ' + str(slistner_bind_port))

    while True:
        slistner_bind_sclient, slistner_bind_sclient_ad = slistner_bind.accept()
        ###### block note start ###
        #### the incall_add should be a list for multiple incalls at once #####
        incall_add = str(slistner_bind_sclient_ad[0])
        ###### block note end ####
        print('incall from: ' + incall_add + ' at port: ' +  str(slistner_bind_port))
        time.sleep(15)  #####  needs to be edited later #########
        if action == '':
            slistner_bind_sclient.send(bytes('no answer',"utf-8"))
        elif action == 'picked up':
            sstream_bind_thread.start()
            slistner_bind_sclient.send(bytes(action,"utf-8"))
        elif action == 'declined':
            slistner_bind_sclient.send(bytes(action,"utf-8"))

slistner_bind_thread = threading.Thread(target = listnerbind)

class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.x !=0:
            theapp.screenm.current = "secondscreen" 

class secscreen(Widget):
    waiter = StringProperty()
    callerid = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        global outcall_add
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callcheck, 0.5)     

    def callcheck(self, *args):
        global incall_add 
        self.waiter = incall_add
        self.callerid = incall_add

    def decline(self):
        global action 
        action = "declined"

    def pickup(self):
        global action
        action = "picked up"
        theapp.screenm.current = "thirdscreen"

    def call(self):
        global callconnect
        global outcall_add
        self.ip = self.ids.ipcall.text
        outcall_add = self.ip
        theapp.screenm.current = "thirdscreen"
        if outcall_add != '':
            print('')
            #### note start  sstreamer_bind_thread should also start  but i dont have another camera###
            #callconnect()
            scall_CON_thread.start()
            ########## note end ########
            


class thscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        global sfeed_cv_frame_recieve, endcall
        Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
        #######################
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.feedupdate, 0.01)

    def feedupdate(self, dt):          # MULTIPLE USERS NEDSS MORE WORK OF POS AND SIZE AFTER SOCKETS
        global sfeed_cv_frame_recieve, endcall
            ############## note begin sfeed_cv_frame_recieve is converted to texture ############
        if sfeed_cv_frame_recieve is not None and endcall == False:
    

            self.frame = sfeed_cv_frame_recieve
            buf1 = cv2.flip(self.frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                    size=(self.frame.shape[1], self.frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
                     
            self.texture = image_texture
            
            with self.canvas:       
                Rectangle(texture=self.texture, pos=(self.pos[0], self.pos[1]+(self.size[1]*0.1)), size=(self.size[0],self.size[1]*0.9))
            ###################### note end ##############
        elif endcall == True:   
            theapp.screenm.current = "secondscreen"
            
    def hangup(self):
        global endcall
        endcall = True

        endcall_string = 'endcall'
        print(endcall_string)
        theapp.screenm.current = "secondscreen"


class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() #(transition=FadeTransition())

        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.secscreen = secscreen()
        screen  = Screen(name = "secondscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.secscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.thscreen = thscreen()
        screen  = Screen(name = "thirdscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.thscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()
    slistner_bind_thread.start()                                            ###########   LISTING THREAD 
    threading.Thread(target = theapp.run())            ################ GUI APP THREAD
```

**and here is the.kv file**

```
<fscreen>
    Label:
        text: '0I Mechanics'
        font_size: root.width*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.8
        

<secscreen>
    TextInput:
        id: ipcall
        hint_text: 'Ip'
        width: root.width*0.3
        height: root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.8

    Button:
        text: 'call'
        width: root.width*0.3
        height: root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.7
        on_press: root.call()

    Label:
        
        text: root.callerid
        font_size: root.width*0.02
        pos: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.4

    Button:
        text: 'pickup'
        width: root.width*0.2
        height: root.height*0.05
        disabled: True if root.waiter == 'nocalls' else False
        pos: root.width*0.5, root.height*0.3
        on_press: root.pickup()

    Button:
        text: 'decline'
        width: root.width*0.2
        height: root.height*0.05
        disabled: True if root.waiter == 'nocalls' else False
        pos: root.width*0.3, root.height*0.3
        on_press: root.decline()


<thscreen>
    Widget:

        Button:
            text: 'hangup'
            width: root.width*0.2
            height: root.height*0.05
            pos: root.width*0.45, root.height*0.01
            on_press: root.hangup()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? You can set up a connection and get audio streaming from point to point, but when you disconnect and try to reconnect, then ...?

Comment: If you want to use threads for more than one "job", look into using a thread pool. You submit jobs to the pool, the pool picks a thread and executes in it, but the thread doesn't close when the job is done. Internally, it would just have the threads run a loop that can receive jobs from a queue or something similar. You could write your own version of that as well if need be

Comment: Re, "How to trick..." Never a good idea to "trick" a library into doing something for you that the designers did not intend it to do. There might be a trick that works today, but there will be no guarantee that the same trick will work when a new version of the library comes out, or when somebody runs your program on a different platform, etc.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the comment was helpful,  when i started coding this i didnt have too much experience with threads i only used them for simple tasks.  i took a shortcut with a premature approach  slicing the code  into function blocks. its clear now i only need  2 threads with the gui at most.